# Firebase dynamic links modifying redirect url only on mobile Safari and Chrome in iOS. Im using angular auxilary outlet

Tags: angular, firebase, url, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase dynamic links rest API in order to make a short urls for which leads to my application. I'm using angular auxiliary outlets, so the final url could looks like this (domain name changed, because its nda` ed)

`http://my-domain.com/#/explorer/(layout:flat)?id=23232323`

Short url that redirects to my url will looks like this
`https://rvst.page.link/1234`

It works fine on PC, however when I'm trying to open this link on is, it becomes:

`http://my-domain.com/#/explorer/%28layout:flat%29?id=23232323`

Angular does not recognize my auxiliary outlet param and just redirects to default page.

That's how response headers from firebase looks like, maybe this could help:

```
HTTP/2 302
content-type: application/binary
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 11:04:04 GMT
location: http://my-domain.com/#/explorer/(layout:flat)?id=23232323
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: script-src 'nonce-Iqw123qASFq3123' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /_/DurableDeepLinkUi/cspreport;worker-src 'self'
server: ESF
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to fix that is to add `location.href = decodeURIComponent(location.href)`on initialization of root angular component. But this is a bit crutchy solution.